# Getting data from a FastAPI endpoint to a svelte frontend app

Tags: svelte, fastapi, sveltekit

I am trying to build a simple app with Svelte to learn.

in my FastAPI backend (main.py) I simply have an endpoint hello:

```
@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    return "Hello"
```

I have the middlewares set up like this so requests from svelte should be allowed:

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost:5173",
    "localhost:5173"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
```

In the svelte app I have:

```
function getHello()
  {
    fetch("hello").then(d => d.text);
  }

console.log("the hello message", getHello());
```

but I get:

```
the hello message undefined
```

I have tried this with a similar template I have from reacts useQuery which seems to work.
I am thinking I might be setting up the folders wrong.

FastAPI is in /backend

and the svelte app is in /my-app/src just from the basic tutorial installation.

Any pointers and tips on things to try and get this set up is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can test whether your endpoint works by just accessing its URL directly. Also, in the application use the browser dev tools to see what is being fetched.

Comment: Thanks H.B! The endpoint I checked but I wasn't aware I was using the function below wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you use to fetch the data cannot work like this.

- The function returns nothing
- The calling code (inside the `log`) does not account for it being asynchronous

(Also, the path `'hello'` is relative, so this will only work with the correct site path in the browser.)

If the path is correct and the server works, the code should look more like this:

```js
function getHello() {
    return fetch("hello").then(d => d.text);
}

getHello().then(text => console.log("the hello message", text));
```

Alternative `async` functions could be used or Svelte's `{#await}` directive.

```js
(async () => {
  console.log("the hello message", await getHello()));
})();
```

```html
{#await getHello() then text}
  {text}
{/await}
```